# Pass Blank space in Json value in curl command string in Java

Tags: java, json, string, curl, space

I am sending a POST request using curl command string in Java. I am passing json in the command string which has spaces in the values. I am getting an error when compiler encounters space in json.  I need to retain spaces and pass the values in the string curl command. Please help. i would be great if someone can re-write my string[] command to help me understand my mistake. Here is my code.

```
String[] command = { "curl", "-X", "POST", "http://my.url.com/add", "-H", "accept: application/json", "-H", "AuthorizationToken: 123", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-d", "{\"FieldLabels\":\"Name,Status,Employee number\",\"FieldValues\":\"test7,Planned,Raj Kumar(123)\",\"Type\":\"BT\"}" };

            ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            Process p;
            try 
            {
            p = process.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            builder.append(line);
                            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            String result = builder.toString();
            System.out.print(result);

            }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Error:

        {
          "message" : {
            "statusCode" : "500",
            "Status" : "Internal Server Error",
            "requestedURI" : "/api/EFormService/createEFormItemData",
            "error" : "Expected a ':' after a key at character 25 of {FieldLabels:Name,Status,Employee"
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the json request in a file and use the below format in the curl request

```
--data "@<path/to/file>"
```

'@' represent the request data is in a file in the path follows.

for your example:

data:

> {"FieldLabels":"Name,Status,Employee
>   number","FieldValues":"test7,Planned,Raj Kumar(123)","Type":"BT"}

this data need to be saved into a file eg: ***/tmp/reqData***
then below is your command

```
{ "curl", "-X", "POST", "http://my.url.com/add", "-H", "accept: application/json", "-H", "AuthorizationToken: 123", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-d", "@/tmp/reqData" };
```

Comment: I cannot pass the request from a file because I also need to pass data from sql next. I am trying to pass parameters manually first here.

Comment: Then try escaping the space character also
**{ "curl", "-X", "POST", "http://my.url.com/add", "-H", "accept: application/json", "-H", "AuthorizationToken: 123", "-H", "Content-Type: application/json", "-d", "{\"FieldLabels\":\"Name,Status,Employee\ number\",\"FieldValues\":\"test7,Planned,Raj\ Kumar(123)\",\"Type\":\"BT\"}" };**

Comment: It still throws an error "Illegal escape character" if i add \ before a space

Comment: Why cont you use HttpClient for triggering this request ?

Comment: Hi Sarath, yes it would be convenient if i could use httpclient or httpurlconnection. i can create a json object. please provide me any links which i can refer to set connection header parameters and pass json object in body.

Answer (score 0):

i have created JSON object, opened a connection with httpurlconnection, set header parameters and pass jason object in body. it worked. Thanks Sarath.